# Как настроить Postfix?

Tags: postfix, email, php, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Не могу до конца разобраться, прошу вашей помощи, на сервере стоит ubuntu 14.04, а на нем установил Postfix.

Шлю письмо через консоль:

mail -s "тема письма" user@gmail.com
cc
тело письма
CTRL+D

Письмо приходит

Но когда шлю на [@mail](/users/15729/maila1501).ru, письмо не доходит, и в логах я вижу [такое](http://pastebin.com/W1K7kf3m).

Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

PTR записи нужно настроить. :)

Answer (score 0):

> said: 550 Sorry, we do not accept mail from hosts with dynamic IP or
>   generic DNS PTR-records. Please get a custom reverse DNS name from
>   your ISP for your host 46.8.13.30

1 Убедитесь что вашего IP нет с спам/паблик базах
https://2ip.ru/spam/?ip=46.8.13.30 (Вам повезло, его там нет)

2 Убедитесь, что у вас в настройках postfix указано корректное имя хоста, а не localhost, ubuntu, или mysite.ru.

```
postconf -n | grep myhostname
```

Если это не так, то укажите в `/etc/postfix/main.cf` корректное имя хоста, то есть ваш домен, указывающий на ваш IP 46.8.13.30
например:

```
myhostname = correct.domain.ru
mydomain = $myhostname
```

3 Убедитесь, что обратная зона (PTR запись) вашего IP соответствует вашему домену correct.domain.ru

```
ping correct.domain.ru
```

Если это не так, то попросите вашего провайдера интернета указать обратную зону (PTR запись) вашего выделенного IP на ваш домен correct.domain.ru.

После этого почта должна приниматься всеми популярными почтовыми серверами.